Issue with Iteration/Unique Naming in QGIS Model Building
this is probably a straightforward problem, but I am a beginner at QGIS and having trouble fixing it.
The Task
I am trying to use a vector of polygons as masks to individually cut out snips of a background raster, and save the resulting .tifs into a folder. This is fairly easy to do with the Clip Raster by Mask tool, but I also need the resulting .tifs to be named based on the value that each polygon has for a field called 'MaskID'.
Work
To do this task, I have been using the model builder. I selected the inputs as a Raster layer (Background Orthomosaic), Vector Features (Mask Polygons), and a Folder (save_as). I am running the raster and vector features through the Clip Raster by Mask tool as before, with the following settings:

The Problem
When I run this model and make sure to select the green iteration button, however, it does not work. I am not given any red error codes in the log, but the algorithm only runs for 1 of the 300 iterations. The remainder say "Executing iteration 2/300… Model processed OK. Executed 0 algorithms total in 0s" until it reaches 300/300. Additionally, the first iteration output populates temporary data on my computer, rather than into the folder I specify with "save_to". What could be the problem here? I have tried several alterations, and I can only get it to save 'properly' when I run it without iterations and specify an output file (rather than a dynamic name)
