Accessing current feature attribute, when iterating over vector features input in QGIS Model Builder
I am trying to develop a process with the model builder in QGIS (3.38) where the process loads a CSV file as vector features, for the ability to go over each combination at a row level. The later part of the algorithm uses the row i.e. feature to get the WFS layer and save it to SQL.
The csv file has a name and id, amongst which id is used in the get WFS step. I am after the ability to refer to the current feature in the iteration. I've tried the @id, and @feature variables available with the precalculated value, without any result.
I could access the field if I use an absolute number against the id rather than using @id or use $current_feature directly:
concat(@var_TypeNameHeader, to_string(attribute(get_feature_by_id(@select_layers_table, 1), @layer_id_field)))

Example like this one - Iterate Graphical Model over a set of numbers in a non geometric layer
The solutions on SE are mostly diverging to the Python side and I am looking for solutions within graphic modeler inputs or algorithms.

another similar issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/483687/issue-with-iteration-unique-naming-in-qgis-model-building
